# spring data -How to sort a list using a calculated column

Tags: sql, sorting, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to sort a list by a calculated column using `Pageable` object.

example:

```
select  qte, price, (price * qte ) as total 
from table 
order by total
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not reference an alias in the order by clause.  Instead you would use:

```
SELECT qte, price, (price * qte) as total 
FROM table 
ORDER BY  (price * qte)
```